# Can I set HDMI resolution to 320x240?

Tags: hdmi, screen-resolution

I have [this](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/High-quality-Portable-LED-Video-TV-Beamer-Projector-for-Home-Theater-Cinema-Multimedia-Player-with-HDMI/32288406700.html) 50 $ projector and I connect a [Dongle](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Bluetooth-Android-4-2-Mini-PC-TV-Box-Stick-MK908-Quad-Core-8GB-RK3188-Cortex-A9/32249664064.html) to it with HDMI cable-- so I have actual screen of 320x240, but the screen is broadcast at 720p. This results in unreadable letters, even if I set font size to huge setting. Can I somehow change the resolution dongle works?

Comment: can you explain us what kind of device you're running and projector ?

Comment: Device is MK-808 dongle, projector is Chinese noname brand with native resolution 320x240 - something similar to the link I posted in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps. 
On my Note3 running Lollipop I was able to check for supported external resolutions by running ( via a terminal app or adb shell )

```
>dmesg
```

and ( filtering with grep ) looking for the lines:

```
<6>[  581.051746] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 1 [640x480 p60 4/3], Supported
<6>[  581.051756] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 1 [640x480 p60 4/3], Supported by MHL
<6>[  581.051767] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 16 [1920x1080 p60 16/9], Supported
<6>[  581.051777] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 16 [1920x1080 p60 16/9], Not-Supported by MHL
<6>[  581.051790] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 4 [1280x 720 p60 16/9], Supported
<6>[  581.051801] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 4 [1280x 720 p60 16/9], Supported by MHL
<6>[  581.051812] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 133 [1280x1024 p60 5/4], Not-Supported
<6>[  581.051822] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 133 [1280x1024 p60 5/4], Not-Supported by MHL
<6>[  581.051833] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 132 [1024x768 p60 4/3], Not-Supported
<6>[  581.051843] hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format: 132 [1024x768 p60 4/3], Not-Supported by MHL
```

which you'll note correspond to supported resolutions in:

```
>cat /sys/devices/virtual/graphics/fb1/edid_modes 
1,4
```

then select your preferred output using :

```
>setprop hw.hdmi.resolution 1
```

and then re-plug the mhl adapter.

which in my case resulted in 640x480 which was the only option supported by my 800x600 projector.

Thanks to this [Force 720p Resolution on InForce 6540](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/114693/force-720p-resolution-on-inforce-6540)