# Change Resolution of HDMI output (USB-C / Slimport)

Tags: 7.0-nougat, usb-connection-mode, terminal, hdmi, screen-resolution

I have been working on this problem to avail

I want to change the screen resolution of my EXTERNAL monitor connected to my android phone. Phone is android 7.0 LG v20, and I am using a USB-C Hub with an HDMI cable to my ULtrawide 21:9 monitor. The problem is, the phone displays at it's native resolution; 16:9, giving black bars on the screen. I have done lots of research, and it apparently is possible to change the hdmi output resolution

However, I am wanting to change the resolution to a different one aspect ratio, (2560x1080P), not lower the resolution like in these questions:

[Example A](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/109343/can-i-set-hdmi-resolution-to-320x240)

[Example B](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124442/how-to-change-external-screen-resolution)

And, when running the code dmesg and filtering with "hdmi" or "edid," the 
`hdmi_edid_add_sink_video_format: EDID: format:` never comes up. I did try `>cat /sys/devices/virtual/graphics/fb1/edid_modes` which got me quite a few options/numbers, however I have no idea which is which and if they are supported. Anyone have a solution?

I do NOT want to change the entire resolution of the phone through ADB, I know you can change it with `adb shell wm (resolution)` but I have read of issues such as black screens and It is irreversible without ADB/ a terminal emulator, I wouldn't always want the phone in ultrawide mode.